# Create a connection to GitHub Enterprise Server on AWS Codepipeline host

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-enterprise

I want to connect Github Enterprise to Codepipeline.
A problem occurred when connecting host from AWS console to github enterprise.
After creating the host, click the "set host" button in the pendding.
What should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opkZp.png)

Comment: Hey Json, which version of GitHub Enterprise are you using?

Comment: hi. I'm using 2.16.9 version